# Email sending in Laravel5

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to send email from my localhost in laravel 5 using `driver: smtp` and `host: smtp.gmail.com`
here is my sample code for sending email after successful account open.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $password = PropertyHelper::randomPassword();
        $arrUser = [
            '_token'    => $request->input('_token'),
            'name'      => $request->input('name'),
            'mobile'    => $request->input('mobile'),
            'email'     => $request->input('email'),
            'password'  => $password,
            'password_confirmation' => $password
        ];
        $validator = $this->registrar->validator($arrUser);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }
        $data = [
            'name'      => $request->input('name'),
            'password'  => $password,
            'email'     => $request->input('email'),
        ];

        $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($arrUser));

        $data = [
            'name'      => $request->input('name'),
            'password'  => $password,
        ];
       $emailSend = Mail::send('emails.signup', $data, function($message){
            $message->to(Auth::user()->email)
                ->subject('নতুন একাউন্ট');
        });
        dd($emailSend); //output 1
        if($emailSend)
        {
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
    }
```

Here is my config/mail.php file

```
return [
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => ['address' => 'hizbul25@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'myEmail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'gmailPassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

This code did not show any error but not also send email. If i try to print the out of email send it says 1. Any idea please ??

Comment: Do you have the from array set in config/mail.php? This caught me out once..

Comment: yeah i have configure everything in mail.php file. Please take a look @fire

Comment: try count(Mail::failures()) instead of dd($emailSend) and check the count

Comment: Your Laravel smtp settings seem to be correct.  I doubt this is a Laravel issue.  If you're going to be sending email with your gmail account, you need to first enable access for less secure apps:  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en.  After that's  done, in order for Google not to blacklist the server you're sending email from, you're going to need to white list it using the Google unlock captcha: https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha.  Turn the unlock captcha on and then try sending an email?

Comment: Yes it was gmail security enable issue, but i did not get any error or warning due to localhost server. After restarting server i got error message and find out solution

Answer (score 0):

try to change the mail info inside .inv under root folder instead of mail.php as previous versions of laravel

Comment: i have fixed my issue, My email configuration is in .env file but in here i show this in mail.php file for readability.